# How do Catholics explain Mary making sin offering 40 days after Jesus' birth?"

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, gospel-of-luke, leviticus, immaculate-conception

The Bible reports that in accord with the requirement of the Mosaic Law, 40 days after Jesus’ birth Mary offered at the temple in Jerusalem a sin offering for purification from uncleanness. If she inherited no sin and imperfection from Adam why  would she have done this?—Luke 2:22-24; Lev. 12:1-8.

Comment: I guess the next question for Catholics may be: was Mary aware of her sinless condition?

Comment: @pam that to has been asked.

Comment: @marc thanks I will look before I leap next time. this site is very cool because if the civility between the asker and answerer.